# What is an example of $E/F,L/E$ are normal but $L/F$ is not.

Tags: field-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $E/F,L/E$ be normal field extensions.

What would be an example such that $L/F$ is not normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]/\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[4]{2}]/\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ are normal, but $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[4]{2}]/\mathbb Q$ is not.